# Modify the program so it inputs a list of 32-bit integers from the user, and then displays the integers in reverse order

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

For my assignment I need to take this program shown below.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
aName BYTE "Abraham Lincoln",0
nameSize = ($ - aName) - 1

.code
main PROC

; Push the name on the stack.
    mov ecx,nameSize
    mov esi,0

L1: movzx eax,aName[esi]    ; get character
    push eax    ; push on stack
    inc esi
    Loop L1

; Pop the name from the stack, in reverse,
; and store in the aName array.
    mov ecx,nameSize
    mov esi,0

L2: pop eax ; get character
    mov aName[esi],al   ; store in string
    inc esi
    Loop L2

; Display the name.
    mov edx,OFFSET aName
    call Writestring
    call Crlf

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

and modify the program so it inputs a list of 32-bit integers from the user, and then displays the integers in reverse order. The build fails saying that instruction operands must be the same size on

```
mov aName[esi],al ; store in string
```

This is the full program.  What am I failing to do?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
   aName WORD 5 DUP (?)
   nameSize = 5
.code

main PROC

   mov  edx, OFFSET aName
   mov  ecx, 4          ;buffer size - 1


   ; Push the name on the stack.
   mov ecx,nameSize
   mov esi,0
   L1: 
     Call ReadInt
     push eax ; push on stack
     inc esi
   Loop L1
   ; Pop the name from the stack, in reverse,
   ; and store in the aName array.
   mov ecx,nameSize
   mov esi,0
   L2: pop eax ; get character
     mov aName[esi],al ; store in string
     inc esi
   Loop L2
   ; Display the name.
   mov edx,OFFSET aName
   call Writestring
   call Crlf
   exit
   main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It is not functioning properly.  Is my code correct to do what I asked/ if not what is needed to do so.

Comment: "It is not functioning properly" is not a question. What are you expecting it to do, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: Did you read my post fully? I need to modify the program so it inputs a list of 32-bit integers from the user, and then displays the integers in reverse order. It fails to build and is saying instruction operands must be the same size.

Comment: I did. Your question does not say the code fails to build, and you haven't shown us the exact error message and line.

Comment: What do you think are the operand sizes in the `mov aName[esi],al`? What do you think determined those sizes? Why do you think the assembler is complaining about them?

Comment: I changed them both to 32 bit registers and it outputed +1

Answer (score 1):

1. This declaration sets up for 16 bit values and your assignment is about 32 bit integers!

   ```
   aName WORD 5 DUP (?)
   ```
2. In assembler most of the time operands have to mach regarding size. Here AL clearly is a byte whereas you defined aName to be of type word! Both need to become dword.

   ```
   mov aName[esi],al ; store in string
   ```
3. The example program uses Writestring to display zero-terminated text. Why do you expect it to also  display a non-zero-terminated buffer filled with numbers in stead of characters?

   ```
   mov edx,OFFSET aName
   call Writestring
   ```
4. Can you see this code does not need both uses of ESI?

   ```
   ; Push the name on the stack.
   mov ecx,nameSize
   mov esi,0
   L1: 
    Call ReadInt
    push eax ; push on stack
    inc esi
   Loop L1
   ```